# How to display axios response in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm new in Vue.js and don't quite understand how it works. So, my function send data to server and get a response, using axios. When response has been got, I want to display it, using a variable, but something goes wrong at this point.

HTML template

```
<p v-if="text"> {{ text }} </p>
```

Vue:

```
const text = ref(undefined);

axios.post('api', anotherVar).then( 
 function (response) {
    response.data.error ? (text.value = response.data.error, console.log(text.value)) : (console.log('Everything is OK'));
     
});
```

Comment: If you're interested in debugging Vue components you should install the [Vue developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) Chrome Extension (or search an equivalent for the browser you're using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will work like this.

```
const text = ref(undefined);
    axios.post('api', anotherVar).then( 
     function (response) {
      text.value = response.data.error ? response.data.error  : 'Everything is OK'; 

     if(text.value != undefined ) console.log(text.value)

    });
```

Comment: I've forgotten to add that in template my <p> block has v-if and I want to display it only if text occurred in real time. I mean this text should be displayed in console and on screen at the same moment. I've also tried your solution, it doesn't show text on screen

Comment: you can try like this

Comment: Don't work. Maybe the problem is in ref() or in how v-if get this value?

Comment: text.value = ..

What does console.log(text.value) print?

Comment: (<class 'AttributeError'>,  <traceback object at 0x282fdf600>), for example